# How do i make whole area clickable

Tags: html, css

Creating a navigation bar. How do i make the whole area around the text not just the text clickable? I put display: block; and it still does not work. Now I'm just writing anything so i could post the question. Thank you!

```
.containter{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
header{
    background: deeppink;
    }
header::after{
    content:'';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    }
.logo{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }
nav{
    float: left;
    }
nav ul{
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
nav li{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    }
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: times new roman;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    }

nav a:hover{
    background-color: #C71585;
    }
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change to these two

```
nav li{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    }
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: times new roman;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For making the area clickable you can use pointer events property of css like

```
    div {
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    div{
      pointer-events: auto; 
    }

    div{
      pointer-events: all; 
    }
```

Can try it out if it works for you none will disable the mouse click where as auto and all will allow the mouse click..!!